# What is "Debug JS Remotely" doing?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, bundle

Can anyone explain how is it that running the app with "Debug JS Remotely" behaves differently than without it? Currently, my app seems to behave differently between these two modes.

To be specific, when my app is in "Debug JS Remotely", it can fire API requests and get responses successfully. When the app is not in "Debug JS Remotely", it's unable to fire API requests?

Comment: from my experience , I have seen so many weird things when I don't use debug mode.So , I always use debug mode even though sometimes it makes the app slow in development mode

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue you're experiencing might be due to the different Javascript engines involved:

- When running on the device, your code will run on the JavascriptCore engine which is bundled with the RN app itself.
- When running the remote debugger, your code will run on Chrome's V8 engine, not on the device.

Different environments might behave differently. Take the following example from this [article](https://medium.com/@suyogkrazz/you-should-not-always-rely-on-remote-debugging-react-native-787a850c7ad8):

Without remote debugging:

```
new Date("2017-02-12 23:51:31")
  .toLocaleDateString('en-US', { day: '2-digit', month: 'short' })  // 02/12/17
```

With remote debugging:

```
new Date("2017-02-12 23:51:31")
  .toLocaleDateString('en-US', { day: '2-digit', month: 'short' })  // Feb 12
```

For this reason, I prefer to sometimes use third-party implementations of some native features (like [whatwg-fetch](https://github.com/github/fetch) instead of using native fetch).

---

Resources:

- [React Native Architecture - Javascript VM](https://www.reactnative.guide/3-react-native-internals/3.1-react-native-internals.html#architecture-%F0%9F%A4%96)

Comment: Hmm, I running the app on devices with "debug JS remotely" and it's working fine. You mean even the app is running on devices, but since it's "debug JS remotely", so it ran on chrome V8 engine instead?

Comment: Yes, when you are in "Debug JS Remotely", the code will be executed in Chrome V8 even though the UI updates are happening on the device. Imagine it as Chrome making calculations and later passes the results to the device so it can update the UI.

Comment: Then it's really tough to debug. The problem i'm facing is actually only one particular iPhone device unable to fire API request, but other devices including both android and iOS are working fine. For this very particular iPhone device, any recommended ways to deal with it in terms of debugging what exactly going on? Again many thanks for your kind input

Comment: Check if that particular iOS device has a different iOS version from you other devices. This is because React Native, on iOS, uses the JavascriptCore engine provided by the system. So, if you have different system versions, you have different engine versions (which can behave differently). If, however, all your iOS devices use the same version I sadly have no suggention.

Comment: Sadly that's situation I'm facing, the problematic device is iPhone 6 with iOS 11 but the same app working fine in iPhone X with iOS 11. Running on iPhone 6 simulator with iOS 11 is working fine too. struggling big time with this issue. Anyway thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Hi as Explained by @Matei above The issue you're experiencing might be due to the different Javascript engines involved
In my case code was running fine in debug mode but as soon i off debug mode screen get stuck

Solution:
`So what worked for me was removing all the console.log from the file.
So just remove all the console.log from your code and it will work like a charm.`